# Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'

Tags: ionic3, angular4-httpclient

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
postData(credentials, type){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers}).
      subscribe(res =>{
        resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) =>{
        reject(err);
      });

    });

  }
```

> Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]:
>   string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'. Types of
>   property 'headers' are incompatible. Type 'Headers' is not assignable
>   to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'. Type
>   'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string |
>   string[]; }'. Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this:

```
postApi(link, data){
     let headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.post(this.globalUrl+link, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(data => {
            resolve(data);
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log("Error" + err)
        })
    });
}
```